# Come possono i verbi bivalenti transitivi trasformarsi in verbi che reggono un oggetto indiretto?

Tags: verbs

Forse sto sbagliando qualcosa nella mia analisi, ma questo fenomeno mi confonde:

Il verbo “lavare” nella frase “Io lavo la sua macchina” mi sembra un verbo bivalente transitivo che regge solo due argomenti: il soggetto e l’oggetto diretto.

Ma questa frase può trasformarsi in una frase con un oggetto diretto e indiretto, facendo così: “Gli lavo la macchina”, in cui compare l’oggetto indiretto e scompare l’aggettivo possessivo.

La mia domanda è, qual è il processo di trasformazione che si sta verificando qui? Che ruolo grammaticale ha “gli”, che non mi sembra un complemento di termine?

Grazie.

Comment: Non sono sicuro di capire il tuo problema, comunque gli  è un pronome, io lavo la macchina a lui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non vedrei la frase “gli lavo la macchina” come una “trasformazione” di “lavo la sua macchina”. È una frase diversa, con un significato molto simile, ma non uguale. Nella frase con “gli”, per esempio, non è detto in modo esplicito che la macchina sia della persona di cui stiamo parlando: potrebbe usarla lui senza che sia sua.

Ciò detto, volendo inquadrare quel pronome in termini di complementi classici, direi che sia un [complemento di vantaggio](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/vantaggio-e-svantaggio-complementi-di_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/): nella pagina che cito c'è tra gli esempi “Gli (= per lui) ho preparato una cena deliziosa”, che mi sembra analogo alla frase sul lavaggio della macchina.

In termini di grammatica valenziale non vedo particolari problemi: “lavo” ha sempre due argomenti (“io” sottinteso e “la macchina”), mentre “gli” è un elemento accessorio.